# How to install an autoconfig proxy only for the VPN interface when it's connected

Tags: macos, vpn, proxy

In OS X I am using the networksetup tool to enable and put in an autoconfig proxy URL, which works great.

Now I am trying to do this for just the VPN service when it's connected.

The problem I have is that the name of the VPN service changes.
Is there a way to use a wild character for the adapter name?

Here is what I have so far:

```
networksetup -setautoproxyurl AGNC_75.100.124.188 http://autoconfig.domain.com/proxy.pac
```

The server address after the underscore is what changes each time a user connects to the VPN.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Operating system is OS X 10.9.5